# Copying untitled columns from tsv file to postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, csv

By tsv I mean a file delimited by tabs. I have a pretty large (6GB) data file that I have to import into a PostgreSQL database, and out of 56 columns, the first 8 are meaningful, then out of the other 48 there are several columns (like 7 or so) with 1's sparsely distributed with the rest being 0's. Is there a way to specify which columns in the file you want to copy into the table? If not, then I am fine with importing the whole file and just extracting the desired columns to use as data for my project, but I am concerned about allocating excessively large memory to a table in which less than 1/4 of the data is meaningful. Will this pose an issue, or will I be fine accommodating the meaningful columns into my table? I have considered using that table as a temp table and then importing the meaningful columns to another table, but I have been instructed to try to avoid doing an intermediary cleaning step, so I should be fine directly using the large table if it won't cause any problems in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Why dont load the whole 50 fields into a temp table, and then create the final table with a `CREATE TABLE finatlTable as SELECT <fieldsYouWant> FROM temporalTable`?

Comment: I actually didn't look closely enough, there are about 60 fields, and out of the 50 meaningless fields, about 7 or so scattered throughout the middle are 1's instead of 0's, so they are not so meaningless. I guess I will put the whole file into a table and just extract the columns I want to use as data for my project. I'm only wary of allocating so much memory when only about less than 1/4 of the data is meaningful, will it cause any problems in PostgreSQL?

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate to the [DBA Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't even know that existed. Thanks for showing me that.

Answer (score 2):

With PostgreSQL 9.3 or newer, `COPY` accepts a program as input . This option is precisely meant for that kind of pre-processing. For instance, to keep only tab-separated fields 1 to 4 and 7 from a TSV file, you could run:

```
COPY destination_table FROM PROGRAM 'cut -f1-4,7 /path/to/file' (format csv, delimiter '\t');
```

This also works with `\copy` in psql, in which case the program is executed client-side.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need. I'm just curious, out of the options 'filename'  | PROGRAM 'command' | stdin given in the PostgreSQL documentation, I'm guessing I have to use the PROGRAM option in order to enable the ability to select specific file columns? Also, it says the default format is text and the default delimiter for text format is \t, so do I actually not need the "format csv" part? Because it seems that if I don't specify anything in the parentheses, it will specify the defaults, text format and tab as the delimiter, which seems to be what I want.

Comment: @Ben: it depends on your contents. The default format for COPY interprets backslash sequences (see the doc for details), which CSV will not do. On the other hand, CSV interprets double quotes around values. To me TSV means CSV with tabs instead of commas and that's exactly what `(format csv, delimiter '\t')` means.

Comment: Apparently (format csv, delimiter '\t') means the same as the default format text and delimiter tab, because both worked the same for me. I tested them without PROGRAM, as that gave me an error.

I tried to use the program 'cut' syntax but it kept telling me (without using E)

    ERROR:  program "cut -f 1     C:\\Users\\....\\Other Files\\allData.txt" failed

,and using E:

    ERROR:  program "cut -f 1 C:\Users\...\Other Files\allData.txt" failed

It seems using E is better but either way, program cut still fails to work.

Comment: Query is: 
    copy time_raw from program E'cut -f 1 C:\\Users\\Other Files\\allData.txt';

I also tried it with cut -f1, but it gave me the same error.

Comment: @Ben: `cut` is a program. Given the `C:\\...` path in your comment, you're using a Windows operating system, so presumably it doesn't have `cut` pre-installed, hence the error.

Comment: Ah, so I can only use pre-installed programs in Windows? And I think I am going to just import all of the data into a temp table and then extract the column I want (first column) from that table into the table I want. By the way, is 'sed' pre-installed to Windows? I'm guessing that as a Unix function like 'cut', it wouldn't be pre-installed either.

Comment: @Ben: personally I install MSYS on Windows, it provides hundreds of Unix-like commands, among which cut, sed, perl, awk, bash...